# The use of square in maths

Tags: real-analysis, variance, philosophy

The variance of a random variable is defined as $E[(X-E[X])^2]$.

In machine learning and linear regressions, loss is sometimes calculated with the squared error.

In both cases, the main function of the square is to prevent positive/negative cancellation. But square introduces non linearity, why people don’t care about this non linearity? If I were to measure something, I hope it changes linearly, it’s easier to grasp.

Is there some long term consequences due to this?

Is there something that has all the good part of abs and square (linear, simple and easy to differentiate)? If so, why people don’t use it?

Comment: You can see it as a convention; there are more metrics we can think of indeed, consider the $p$-norm in finite dimension section on this page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

Comment: And why the square instead of linearity? This is mainly because our intuitive concept of distance (i.e. Euclidian distance in the three dimensional space) is also $L^2$ distance. Furthermore, when we construct a loss function, it is often considered as a desirable property that 'large' deviations contribute to 'more' loss than 'small' deviations. And last but not least, it is just very convenient in statistics.

Comment: Also this article http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-the-l1-norm-and-the-l2-norm-least-absolute-deviations-and-least-squares/ might be interesting for you for the difference of $L^1$ and $L^2$ norms in linear regression